# how to get the path of the instance of imageSpan

Tags: java, android, imagespan

I have added a clicklistener to the spannableString, and I want to get the local path of the imageSpan when I click it, so that I can pass the path to the new activity to display the original image.
  I have used the method *getSource()* of imageSpan, but the method just returns null to me.I can't find the way to solve it.**I need help!**

```
noteContent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Spanned s = noteContent.getText();//得到Spanned对象

            ImageSpan[] image_spans = s.getSpans(0, s.length(), ImageSpan.class); //得到该EditText中多有的ImageSpan对象

            int selectStart = noteContent.getSelectionStart(); //获得当前EditText中的光标位置
            Log.i("info", "cursor: " + selectStart);
            int i = 0;
            //遍历所有的ImageSpan 根据光标位置判断点击的是哪一个ImageSpan
            for (ImageSpan span : image_spans) {
                int start = s.getSpanStart(span);
                int end = s.getSpanEnd(span);
                String path = span.getSource();
                Log.i("info", "start:" + start + ",end:" + end + ",image path:" + path + ",times" + i);
                if (selectStart >= start && selectStart <= end) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "点击了图片", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(NoteActivity.this,PictureDisplayer.class);
                    intent.putExtra("PATH",path);
                    i += 1;
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
            Log.i("info", "times:" + i);
        }
    });
```

The imageSpan is added to the spanned as below,insertBitmap which is public get a bitmap with the path passed from the former activity and call the insertBitmap which is private, and the private insertBitmap generates the imageSpan and then insert it into the spannableString.

```
private SpannableString insertBitmap(String path, Bitmap bitmap) {
    Editable edit_text = getEditableText();
    int index = getSelectionStart(); // get the location of the cursor
    //插入换行符，使图片单独占一行
    SpannableString newLine = new SpannableString("\n");
    edit_text.insert(index, newLine);//插入图片前换行
    // 创建一个SpannableString对象，以便插入用ImageSpan对象封装的图像
    path = mBitmapTag + path + mBitmapTag;
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(path);
    // 根据Bitmap对象创建ImageSpan对象
    ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(mContext, bitmap);
    // 用ImageSpan对象替换你指定的字符串
    spannableString.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, path.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // 将选择的图片追加到EditText中光标所在位置
    if (index < 0 || index >= edit_text.length()) {
        edit_text.append(spannableString);
    } else {
        edit_text.insert(index, spannableString);
    }
    edit_text.insert(index, newLine);//插入图片后换行
    return spannableString;
}


/**
 * 插入图片
 *
 * @param path
 */
public void insertBitmap(String path) {
    Bitmap bitmap = getSmallBitmap(path, 480, 800);
    insertBitmap(path, bitmap);
}
```

Comment: How was the `ImageSpan` added to the `Spanned`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added this part to above.

Comment: You are attaching a `Bitmap` to the `ImageSpan`. The `ImageSpan` has no idea where this `Bitmap` came from. So, from the standpoint of the `ImageSpan`, there is no "local path".

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for telling me this.Could you tell me how can I display the image in a new activity after I click it, or how to show a bigger one in this activity.

Comment: I cannot think of a way to do what you want that will handle configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation).